# angular update / add an item in Firestore query

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to update / add an item in my Firestore query.

I try something like this, but (of course) the result is not updated.
How can I do to have this.chatusers updated ???

```
chatsuserCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
chatusers: Observable<User[]>;
public ChatUsers = (): Observable<User[]> => {
    this.chatsuserCol = this.afs.collection('users');
    this.chatusers = this.chatsuserCol.valueChanges();
    this.chatusers.subscribe(
        items => { 
            items.forEach(function (item, index) {
                item.displayName = 'Name : ' + item.displayName; // Update
                item.avatar = item.photoURL; // Add new field
            });
            alert(JSON.stringify(items));   // items has been updated
        }
    );
    return this.chatusers;  // I WANT TO UPDATE THIS
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.map` instead of `.subscribe`. This will change the data on the fly

Try

```
this.chatsuserCol = this.afs.collection('users');
this.chatusers = this.chatsuserCol.valueChanges().map(users=>{
  users.forEach(user=>{
    user.displayName = 'Name : ' + user.displayName;
    user.avatar = user.photoURL;
  })
  return users;
});
return this.chatusers;
```